# How to correctly combine where and or_where (with foreach loop)

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying the following code:

```
//NEEDS TO BE 'OR's
    foreach ($market_ids as $market_id) {
             $this->CI->db->or_where('market_id',$market_id,FALSE);
             }
//NEEDS TO BE 'AND'
    $this->CI->db->where('market_product.product_id',$product_id,FALSE);
    $this->CI->db->from('market_product');
    $this->CI->db->join('product', 'market_product.product_id = product.product_id');
```

by the result i see that 'where' with the market_product.product_id it also hads a "and".
What i need is ('OR's for the markets and one 'AND' for the product_id.)
but whatever i tried didn't work.. I also looked at other similar questions in stackoverflow but none of them contains the 'foreach' thing or how to solve it.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I know version 3.0 would solve it by grouping but its not officially released yet.

Comment: you can pass condition as string

Comment: consider that i do not know how much $market_ids i will get. can you show example.

Comment: you can do `$this->CI->db->where('(market_id IN ('.implode($market_ids).'))');` and no need loop

Comment: don't get any result when i replaced the foreach with your line.. ummm

Comment: Where to you get the $market_ids from uri segment? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a way to solve your problem

```
//NEEDS TO BE 'OR's
    $where_or = array();
    foreach ($market_ids as $market_id) {
            // $this->CI->db->or_where('market_id',$market_id,FALSE);
         $where_or[] = "market_id = $market_id";
    }
  $this->CI->db->where("(".implode(' OR ',$where_or).")");
//NEEDS TO BE 'AND'
    $this->CI->db->where('market_product.product_id',$product_id,FALSE);
    $this->CI->db->from('market_product');
    $this->CI->db->join('product', 'market_product.product_id = product.product_id');
```

hope this will work for you